# libvirt: how virsh discovers domain capabilties with no qemu running on the node

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I have a `libvirt` installed, and no `qemu` instance is running. However `virsh domcapabilities` dumps XML with domain capabilities:

```
<domainCapabilities>
  <path>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</path>
  <domain>qemu</domain>
  <machine>pc-i440fx-2.11</machine>
  <arch>x86_64</arch>
  ...
  <devices>
     ...
  </devices>
  ...
</domainCapabilities>
```

How does `libvirt` discover all these?

Answer (score 0):

You only get the qemu process running when a VM is running. However libvirt will run the qemu binary to extract those data and cache them. See the [libvirt qemu driver capabilities code](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/blob/master/src/qemu/qemu_capabilities.c)